# How do I generate a sampling path by numbering points?

Tags: qgis, vector, point

I need to number points from left to right and then the next row of points the numbering must continue from right to left, then again from left to right the row thereafter - and so on, and so on.

How do I do this in Qgis?  The points are not necessarily in straight lines.

[image: Points]